# KnockoutJS - show accumulate value for each item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I display in a table the accumulate value for each item in a observableArray with KnockoutJS?

I need somethin like:

```js
function ViewModel(){
var self = this;

self.Item = function(day,note){
this.day = ko.observable(day);
this.note = ko.observable(note);
};
}


var itemsFromServer = [
{day:'Mo', note:1},
{day:'Tu', note:2},
{day:'We', note:3},
{day:'Th', note:4},
{day:'Fr', note:5},
{day:'Su', note:6},
];

var vm = new ViewModel();

var arrItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(itemsFromServer, function(item) {
    return new vm.Item(item.day, item.note);
    });
    
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Day</th><th>Note</th><th>Accumulate</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: arrItems">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: day"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: note"></td>
           <td >the currente 'note' + the anterior 'note'</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The last column should display the sum of current item + anterior item.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what value you want the third column to be, but the main approach remains the same:

- Give your `Item` class access to their "sibling items" by passing a reference to the array
- In a computed property, do a "look behind" by looking up the items own index.
- Perform some sort of calculation between two (or more) `Item` instances and return the value

For example, this `acc` property returns the `acc` of the previous `Item` and ones own `note` property:

```js
var Item = function(day, note, siblings){
  this.day = ko.observable(day);
  this.note = ko.observable(note);

  this.acc = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var allItems = siblings();
    var myIndex = allItems.indexOf(this);
    
    var base = myIndex > 0 
      ? allItems[myIndex - 1].acc() 
      : 0
    
    return base + this.note();
  }, this);
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.items(itemsFromServer.map(function(item) {
      return new Item(item.day, item.note, self.items);
    })
  );
}


var itemsFromServer = [
  {day:'Mo', note:1},
  {day:'Tu', note:2},
  {day:'We', note:3},
  {day:'Th', note:4},
  {day:'Fr', note:5},
  {day:'Su', note:6},
];

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Accumulate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: day"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: note"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: acc"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks